# why has my script stopped working after moving from ganache to geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, geth-debugging

I have built a web application that connects to a private blockchain, the app works like a private token exchange.
Everything works perfectly with ganache/truffle, however the below script i use to seed the exchange with orders has stopped working even though everything is the same other than the blockchain.

Here is the script, i run it with `truffle exec script.js`

```
    // Contracts
const Token = artifacts.require("Token2")
const Exchange2 = artifacts.require("Exchange2")

// Utils
const ETHER_ADDRESS = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' // Ether token deposit address
const ether = (n) => {
  return new web3.utils.BN(
    web3.utils.toWei(n.toString(), 'ether')
  )
}
const tokens = (n) => ether(n)

const wait = (seconds) => {
  const milliseconds = seconds * 1000
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

module.exports = async function(callback) {
  try {
    // Fetch accounts from wallet - these are unlocked
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
console.log(accounts);
    // Fetch the deployed token
    const token = await Token.deployed()
    console.log('Token fetched', token.address)

    // Fetch the deployed exchange
    const exchange2 = await Exchange2.deployed()
    console.log('Exchange fetched', exchange2.address)

    // Give tokens to account[1]
    const sender = accounts[0]
    const receiver = accounts[1]
    let amount = web3.utils.toWei('10000', 'ether') // 10,000 tokens

    await token.transfer(receiver, amount, { from: sender })
    console.log(`Transferred ${amount} tokens from ${sender} to ${receiver}`)

    // Set up exchange users
    const user1 = accounts[0]
    const user2 = accounts[1]

    // User .1 Deposits Ether
    await exchange2.depositEther({ from: user1, value: ether(.1) })
    console.log(`Deposited ${amount} Ether from ${user1}`)

    // User 2 Approves Tokens
    amount = 10000
    await token.approve(exchange2.address, tokens(amount), { from: user2 })
    console.log(`Approved ${amount} tokens from ${user2}`)

    // User 2 Deposits Tokens
    await exchange2.depositToken(token.address, tokens(amount), { from: user2 })
    console.log(`Deposited ${amount} tokens from ${user2}`)

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Seed a Cancelled Order
    //

    // User 1 makes order to get tokens
    let result
    let orderId
    result = await exchange2.makeOrder(token.address, tokens(100), ETHER_ADDRESS, ether(0.01), { from: user1 })
    console.log(`Made order from ${user1}`)

    // User 1 cancells order
    orderId = result.logs[0].args.id
    await exchange2.cancelOrder(orderId, { from: user1 })
    console.log(`Cancelled order from ${user1}`)

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Seed Filled Orders
    //

    // User 1 makes order
    result = await exchange2.makeOrder(token.address, tokens(100), ETHER_ADDRESS, ether(0.01), { from: user1 })
    console.log(`Made order from ${user1}`)

    // User 2 fills order
    orderId = result.logs[0].args.id
    await exchange2.fillOrder(orderId, { from: user2 })
    console.log(`Filled order from ${user1}`)

    // Wait 1 second
    await wait(1)

    // User 1 makes another order
    result = await exchange2.makeOrder(token.address, tokens(50), ETHER_ADDRESS, ether(0.001), { from: user1 })
    console.log(`Made order from ${user1}`)

    // User 2 fills another order
    orderId = result.logs[0].args.id
    await exchange2.fillOrder(orderId, { from: user2 })
    console.log(`Filled order from ${user1}`)

    // Wait 1 second
    await wait(1)

    // User 1 makes final order
    result = await exchange2.makeOrder(token.address, tokens(200), ETHER_ADDRESS, ether(0.015), { from: user1 })
    console.log(`Made order from ${user1}`)

    // User 2 fills final order
    orderId = result.logs[0].args.id
    await exchange2.fillOrder(orderId, { from: user2 })
    console.log(`Filled order from ${user1}`)

    // Wait 1 second
    await wait(1)

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Seed Open Orders
    //

    // User 1 makes 10 orders
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      result = await exchange2.makeOrder(token.address, tokens(10 * i), ETHER_ADDRESS, ether(0.001), { from: user1 })
      console.log(`Made order from ${user1}`)
      // Wait 1 second
      await wait(1)
    }

    // User 2 makes 10 orders
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      result = await exchange2.makeOrder(ETHER_ADDRESS, ether(0.001), token.address, tokens(10 * i), { from: user2 })
      console.log(`Made order from ${user2}`)
      // Wait 1 second
      await wait(1)
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

  callback()
}
```

The error i receive is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'args' of undefined
    at module.exports (seed2.js:68:30)
```

So my questions are how can i fix my script?
I have already tried to change the version of web3 in case this caused the problem, however i also get the same error.

and now i am using geth instead of ganache, do i need to compile and migrate my contracts differently or can i still use
`truffle compile` and `truffle migrate`?

Comment: Which line cause the error?

Comment: @Ismael     orderId = result.logs[0].args.id

Comment: That means `result.logs[0]` is undefined, so it is likely `result.logs` is empty and no event was emitted. Try to console.log `result` to determine the cause, perhaps it run out of gas.